# Microphone stops working in Flutter iOS app using flutter_inappwebview when it goes to the background

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using flutter_inappwebview to show a webview, that has webrtc capabilities, using both camera and video it works fine until the app is set to the background.

When the app is minimized (goes to background), I can still hear other users on the call but my microphone stops working and others cannot hear me.

This does work fine in Android but does not on iOS.

I'm using flutter_inappwebview version 5.3.2, and has the Audio background mode:

```
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: What's the ios version your are targeting?

Comment: I'm targeting ios 10!

Comment: try increasing this to 12 and check once please

Comment: Increased the target to iOS 12 but same result!